# Swift Playground: Show Line Execution Counts > i.e. (# times)

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

I'm running Xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a)
While in the swift playground I'm not seeing line execution counts.

[image: Swift Playground does not show execution counts]

How does one show line execution counts like the "(3 times)" output normally show as the 'output' of line 2, as shown below on line 9 of an example:

[image: Example of Swift Playground with line execution counts shown]

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `line execution counts`?

Comment: by "line execution counts" I mean the "(3 times)" output that I am understanding would normally show as the 'output' of line 2.

Comment: I think this is expected. "3 times" is normally used for loops, not consecutive actions in the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short and simple answer:
There is no calculation iteration to print out there, check this example:
[image]